# Laravel file manager standalone iframe to input

Tags: laravel, iframe

I don't know how can't I find any examples on this, like no one used it before..

I want to open file manager in iframe and on images click to insert image url to input. Their example opens new window...

I am using laravel file manager standalone button to change avatar image but by their docs I can do it like this:

```
<div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
         <a id="lfm" data-input="thumbnail" data-preview="holder" class="btn btn-primary">
           <i class="fa fa-picture-o"></i> Choose
         </a>
       </span>
       <input id="thumbnail" class="form-control" type="text" name="filepath">
     </div>
     <img id="holder" style="margin-top:15px;max-height:100px;">
```

And calling `$('#lfm').filemanager('image');`

Which works but it opens new window because this is `.filemanager()`

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.filemanager = function(type, options) {
    type = type || 'file';

    this.on('click', function(e) {
      var route_prefix = (options && options.prefix) ? options.prefix : '/laravel-filemanager';
      localStorage.setItem('target_input', $(this).data('input'));
      localStorage.setItem('target_preview', $(this).data('preview'));
      window.open(route_prefix + '?type=' + type, 'FileManager', 'width=900,height=600');
      window.SetUrl = function (url, file_path) {
          //set the value of the desired input to image url
          var target_input = $('#' + localStorage.getItem('target_input'));
          target_input.val(file_path).trigger('change');

          //set or change the preview image src
          var target_preview = $('#' + localStorage.getItem('target_preview'));
          target_preview.attr('src', url).trigger('change');
      };
      return false;
    });
  }

})(jQuery);
```

Now changing:

```
window.open(route_prefix + '?type=' + type, 'FileManager', 'width=900,height=600');
```

To:

```
$('iframe').attr('src', route_prefix + '?type=' + type);
```

Will append filemanager to iframe as I want but when I click on image inside  iframe it opens image in new tab as it is setting new url but skipping the script?

I think that I could get image url if it was opening in iframe but it is not...

Do you maybe know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out answer for my needs, not finished one tho but it works as needed:

Open up script.js from vendor/..../js folder and change useFIle function if/else statement where it looks up are you using any editor (cke,mce,etc..) and if not it just opens image in new window.

I remove that option and added this:

```
// parent.document.getElementById(field_name).value = url;
    var target_input = parent.document.getElementById(localStorage.getItem('target_input'));
    target_input.value = url;

    //set or change the preview image src
    var target_preview = parent.document.getElementById(localStorage.getItem('target_preview'));
    target_preview.src = url;
```

From my question you can see jquery-plugin for opening laravel-filemanager into iframe and adding elements to localstorage.

I used that elements from localstorage in iframe to append url in input and display image in holder.

Now I will change this a little bit, since I wan't to leave this script as it is for full manager page on that url. I will just add another field as uri to be able to say this url is opened by iframe and use someOtherFUnction instead of useFile function by default.